# How to prevent Windows partition to access(read) Linux partition files?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, partition, windows, dual-boot

How to prevent Windows partition to access(read) Linux partition files within one physical hard disc?

Right now a couple of programs can do that. E.g. [Linux Reader](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vRftHZTWnWA)

I want to prevent that?

What are my possibilities?

I am currently running Windows 7 and would like to install as a dual boot Linux Mint 15.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [LUKS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Unified_Key_Setup) to encrypt your volumes, and have it when you boot into Mint, it requires a password to mount the volumes.  Windows would be unable to read the volumes after that.

To be honest, I'm not sure if Linux Reader can even read LVM volumes, so you might be able to get away with simply using LVM, but LUKS is most likely going to be the more secure way.

Comment: This password could even be hardcoded. The Windows tools are not going to search the Linux boot disk for possible passwords.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to increase the fun factor of the solution then you could delete the Linux partitions from the partition table and recreate them with every boot from the initrd. If Linux has mounted the partitions (or rather: after the kernel has noticed them by a `kpartx` / `partprobe` call) then you could delete them again (in `/boot/init.d/boot.local` or even at a later stage from the initrd).

Comment: Or: have the partitions permanently deleted, and pass the offset (`-o offset`) to `mount` in the initrd.

Comment: @ignis loop devices are for image files. If you need a part of a block device then you should use `dmsetup` (device mapper).